# Arduino communication

Tags: communication

I want to message and call arduino board. I want some type of automation. But where should I get started I don't know I've tried sim900a module which was disappointing experience for me. Then I found out that this module was designed for asian regions and needed some type of firmware update. I wonder if there are another methods to make calls and send messages to arduino board. Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Choose a modem that is suitable for your region. You should be looking for an LTE modem not a GSM/GPRS modem these days. GSM/GPRS is gradually being phased out.

Comment: SIM900A is not just for Asia, it is supports dual band GSM/GPRS 900/1800MHz which works in Asia, Europe except North America. You should get SIM900B which is a quad-band supporting GSM/GPRS 850/900/1800/1900MHz.